# PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: function array_append(anyarray, anyelement) does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, github, rspec

In my application we have few test cases which are configured with GitHub workflow,Even I do have only space related changes on file but still getting below error. Not sure why my specs are still failing it was working fine before.

```
An error occurred in a `before(:suite)` hook.
Failure/Error: ActiveMedian.create_function

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
  PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function array_append(anyarray, anyelement) does not exist
  :       CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION median(anyarray)
           RETURNS float8 AS
        $$
          WITH q AS
          (
             SELECT val
             FROM unnest($***) val
             WHERE VAL IS NOT NULL
             ORDER BY ***
          ),
          cnt AS
          (
            SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM q
          )
          SELECT AVG(val)::float8
          FROM
          (
            SELECT val FROM q
            LIMIT  2 - MOD((SELECT c FROM cnt), 2)
            OFFSET GREATEST(CEIL((SELECT c FROM cnt) / 2.0) - ***,0)
          ) q2;
        $$
        LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

        DROP AGGREGATE IF EXISTS median(numeric);
        DROP AGGREGATE IF EXISTS median(double precision);
        DROP AGGREGATE IF EXISTS median(anyelement);
        CREATE AGGREGATE median(anyelement) (
          SFUNC=array_append,
          STYPE=anyarray,
          FINALFUNC=median,
          INITCOND='{}'
        );
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:***54:in `seed'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:***:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
# ------------------
# --- Caused by: ---

# PG::UndefinedFunction:
#   ERROR:  function array_append(anyarray, anyelement) does not exist
#   ./spec/rails_helper.rb:***54:in `seed'
```

There is `ActiveMedian.create_function` on `spec/rails_helper.rb` which might causing the issue.

Any lead or suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Can you please add more details to the question like `create_function`, rails, postgres,Also, the things you have tried already etc.?

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: You are using a pg function, so you should check if that function is present in your test db. -- I'm talking about `array_append`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few research, I have resolved this issue by changing the Postgres image version on GitHub as follows.

file **.github/workflows/build.yml**

```
services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:13
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
```

**Solution**: This is an issue with Postgres 14 version, For quick solve downgrade it to Postgres 13.

Answer (score 12):

You are using PostGreSQL 14, aren't you ?

Because with postgres 13 and before, this should work, see the test result in  [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=71a039c18cd246e3d4a15eed699a8f4f).

And I confirm that this doesn't work with postgres 14, see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1081ec7af7d57f2ec88d11c955844729).

The reason is explained in the [PostGres 14 manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/release-14.html#id-1.11.6.6.4) :

> User-defined objects that reference certain built-in array functions
> along with their argument types must be recreated (Tom Lane)
>
> Specifically, **array_append()**, array_prepend(), array_cat(),
> array_position(), array_positions(), array_remove(), array_replace(),
> and width_bucket() **used to take anyarray arguments but now take
> anycompatiblearray**. Therefore, user-defined objects like aggregates
> and operators that reference those array function signatures must be
> dropped before upgrading, and recreated once the upgrade completes.

To make it working, you can do instead :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION median(anycompatiblearray)
RETURNS float8 AS
$$
...
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE ;

...

CREATE AGGREGATE median(anycompatible) (
  SFUNC=array_append,
  STYPE=anycompatiblearray,
  FINALFUNC=median,
  INITCOND='{}'
);
```